# Azure Sphere MT3620 retry later to send to IoT hub

Tags: azure-iot-sdk, azure-sphere

Trying to find any information regarding storing local information on Azure Sphere MT3620 device if the connection was lost. Some sort of failback storage for later retry?

**Example**

```
Try to send a timestamp that the button was press to Azure IoT Hub
Connection failed due to the wifi router was unplugged.
Save that event to some type of on non-volatile storage.
When the chip does comes online the ship send all of the data that it was unable to send when it was offline.
```

Read that the chip has two cores, is it possible to set one to log and the other to send if failure so that core does not block the io events?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mutable storage type of Azure Sphere. Mutable storage stores data that persists when a device reboots. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/app-development/storage) how to do it.

[Edit] The Azure Sphere 19.05 release unlocked the real-time capable cores that reside on the MT3620 (ARM Cortex-M4F). The OS and SDK support development, deployment, and debugging SPI, I2C, GPIO, UART and ADC real-time capable apps on the MT3620’s two M4 cores.